# text input's placeholder doesnt support RTL when using password type in React native

Tags: react-native

when I want to use password type in text input with secureTextEntry props, placeholder doesn't support RTL

```
<TextInput style={styles.input}
                                   value={this.state.password}
                                   secureTextEntry={true}
                                   placeholder="الزامی"
                                   underlineColorAndroid="transparent"
                                   onChangeText={(text) => this.setState({password: text})}/>
```

and result

[image]

What is the solution to this problem?

Comment: Please share CSS too. Thanks

Comment: Do you mean style?

Comment: I just write a basic **direction: rtl** example, I hope it'll help you out. Thanks

Comment: but this is a web solution , this bug for react native app

Comment: I just update my answer, I hope it'll help you out. Thanks

Answer (score 6):

Please check this code snippet, its working with RTL and LTR conditions. I have also attach code snippet [snack.expo.io](https://snack.expo.io/S1JFxhw_4)

```
import { I18nManager,Text,TextInput, View, StyleSheet } from 'react-native';

    <View style={{ borderWidth: 1, marginTop: 20, borderColor: '#000' }}>
          <TextInput
            style={{
              color: '#000',
              borderColor: '#000',
              textAlign: I18nManager.isRTL ? 'right' : 'left',
            }}
            value={this.state.password}
            placeholder="الزامی"
            placeholderTextColor="#303030"
            secureTextEntry={true}
            underlineColorAndroid="transparent"
            onChangeText={text => this.setState({ password: text })}
          />
        </View>
```

You need to add **I18nManager** to check your UI is in RTL mode or in LTR mode

Answer (score 0):

you need to configure your project to support **rtl**. [here](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/blog/2016/08/19/right-to-left-support-for-react-native-apps.html#making-an-app-rtl-ready) is the official guide in react native blog.
Let me know if it worked for you.

Answer (score -2):

I just write a basic code snippet with `direction: rtl;`. I hope it'll help you out. Thanks

```
<TextInput style={styles.input} 
           value={this.state.password} 
           secureTextEntry={true} 
           placeholder="الزامی" 
           underlineColorAndroid="transparent" 
           onChangeText={(text) => 
           this.setState({password: text})}
           direction ='rtl'
/>
```

Comment: Can you create any fiddle for more clarifications?